# How to create global error handler in Windows Form Application?

Tags: c#, .net, error-handling, components, global

I think there was a component that allowed to create global error handling.

For example I myself throw exception when something bad happens, for example

```
throw new ArgumentNullException("playlist is empty");
```

How can I catch it globally?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MSDN is your friend: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx

Answer (score 8):

**You can accomplish this either through [`AppDomain.UnhandledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) or [`Application.ThreadException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx).**

See the documentation for more details on what these events do and what the difference is for these events. The idea is that `AppDomain.UnhandledException` always works. `Application.ThreadException` is specifically for unhandled UI exceptions.

Comment: AppDomain.UnhandledException is also available on Compact Framework.

Comment: ***Be careful when using the AppDomain.UnhandledException event***

`Revision note`: I was pointed by **Phillip Haack** of this important omission. Other common source of mistakes is the Application.ThreadException event. There are lots of caveats when using them.

Answer (score 2):

To Handle Exceptions Globally...

**Windows Application**

System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException event

*Generally Used in Main Method. Refer [MSDN Thread Exception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx)*

**Asp.Net**

System.Web.HttpApplication.Error event

*Normally Used in Global.asax file. Refer [MSDN Global.asax Global Handlers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24395wz3(v=vs.140).aspx)*

**Console Application**

System.AppDomain.UnhandledException event

*Generally used in Main Method. Refer [MSDN UnhandledException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx)*

Comment: ***Console or Service application***: `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`