# Handling global exceptions without killing the app?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, exception, global

I throw various custom exceptions thoughout my code.

Some of these are recoverable from, so I want a global handler to catch them, display a warning, then carry on.

I have found the `AppDomain.UnhandledException` event which has an `IsTerminating` argument, but this is read only.

Is there some event or other way to catch exceptions globally that still lets you handle them and carry on?

(This is in Forms, but I'd be interesting in a WPF solution too)

Comment: possible duplicate: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862841/how-to-create-global-error-handler-in-windows-form-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have found the solution. Use `Application.ThreadException` instead of `AppDomain.UnhandledException`. But you must also tell it to give exceptions on the UI thread too:

```
public static void SetupGlobalExceptionHandler()
{
    Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
    Application.ThreadException += OnException;
}

static void OnException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs args)
{
    MessageBox.Show("There was a problem. Error is:\n\n" + args.Exception.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the global.asax and the

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Event to catch errors which aren't caught on the page.

Within this, you could use a number of methods, but one such way would be something like this:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception opException = Server.GetLastError();

    switch (opException.GetBaseException().GetType().Name)
    {
        case "OptimisticConcurrencyException":
                        //display a friendly message
                    break;
    }


    Server.ClearError();

}
```

Or something similar

Comment: As I said this is Forms, not ASP.

Comment: Ah sorry, my mistake, I heard 'Forms' and just assumed 'WebForms'!! *facepalm*

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += AppDomainUnhandledException;

public static void AppDomainUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    // You might have to try changing this to your custom exception type and then have overloads or pass it as an object and cast it in the HandleException method
    HandleException(e.ExceptionObject as Exception);
}

private static void HandleException(Exception exception)
{
    if (exception == null) return;

    // Do a check in here against the exceptions that you want to handle or don't want to handle and either display a message, log, quit, etc
}
```

Didn't notice winforms, I haven't done forms in a long time so this is WPF, might work or might need to be tweaked.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm already doing. By the time the event fires the runtime has already decided to kill the app. All I can do it show a message.

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer if you wrap your main Application running command with a try / catch and pass that to HandleException you should be able to call the shutdown / exit yourself

Comment: If I wrap Application.Run then it will exit when an exception is thrown. I don't want to exit the app.

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer it would only exit if you give it an explicit Environment.Exit() or Application.Current.Shutdown() command, because you are catching the error you can handle it as required. Honestly though, if you are getting an unhandled error, you should have the application quit since you will likely have bad data or strange bugs pop up. You should only catch all errors in order to figure out where to provide the correct error handling code.

Comment: If I wrap Application.Run() in a try catch, then the catch is OUTSIDE the Run() function, ie my app is no longer running at the time of catch, so unfortunately not viable. Many thanks for your help but I think I've solved it now anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but the Dispatcher.UnhandledException event has a Handled parameter on it's event args that you can use to stop the application from shutting down.

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.UnhandledException += Dispatcher_UnhandledException;
}
private void Dispatcher_UnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    HandleException(e.Exception);//your handler
    e.Handled = true;
}
```